# How do i make this function return what the Longest common subsequence(not the length of lcs)

Tags: python, recursion

hi was solving this question where i had to return how long the longest common subsequence(lcs) is and i was able to form a recursive function that does the same but now i wonder how to make this function return what the lcs is.
like for example
`seq1 = 'serendipitous'`
`seq2 = 'precipitation'` 
`lcs of seq1 and seq2 is - reipito`

i want to make a function that return 'reipito'

the function that i wrote to return the length of lcs is

```
def lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0):
    
    if idx1 == len(seq1) or idx2 == len(seq2):
        return 0 
        
    if seq1[idx1] == seq2[idx2]:
        return 1 + lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1 + 1, idx2 + 1)
    
    else:
        option1 = lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1 + 1, idx2)
        option2 = lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1, idx2 + 1)
        
        return max(option1, option2)
```

this function returns the length how lcs

i tired to do this but failed. please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find longest intersection between two strings in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61391909/how-to-find-longest-intersection-between-two-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal changes to your code:

```
def lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0, lcs = ''):
    
    if idx1 == len(seq1) or idx2 == len(seq2):
        return lcs
        
    if seq1[idx1] == seq2[idx2]:
        return lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1 + 1, idx2 + 1, lcs + seq1[idx1])
    
    else:
        option1 = lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1 + 1, idx2, lcs)
        option2 = lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1, idx2 + 1, lcs)
        
        return max(option1, option2, key=len)

seq1 = 'serendipitous'
seq2 = 'precipitation'
print(lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2)) # reipito
```

---

Since you're likely calling `lcs_recursive` with the same index pairs multiple times, `functools.cache` if using Python >= 3.9 or `functools.lru_cache` if using Python >= 3.2 may improve performance.

For example, if `seq1 = 'ab'` and `seq2 = 'bd'`, `lcs_recursive('ab', 'bd')` will eventually call `lcs_recursive('ab', 'bd', 2, 1)` twice (you can see this by doing `print(idx1, idx2)` first thing in your function). With the `@lru_cache` optimization bellow, on the first call to `(idx1=2, idx2=1)` (i.e. `lcs_recursive('ab', 'bd', 2, 1)`), the result corresponding to `(idx1=2, idx2=1)` is computed and stored (in a cache, which you can think of as a dictionary). On subsequent calls to the same index pair (`(idx1=2, idx2=1)`), the stored result is looked up so that it doesn't have to be computed all over again. In general, `lru_cache` will memoize results based on the input. That's why in the code below, the function `helper` only takes `idx1` and `idx2` - to make it easier for `lru_cache` to work well.

```
from functools import lru_cache

def lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2):
    @lru_cache
    def helper(idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0):
    
        if idx1 == len(seq1) or idx2 == len(seq2):
            return ''
            
        if seq1[idx1] == seq2[idx2]:
            return  seq1[idx1] + helper(idx1 + 1, idx2 + 1)
        
        option1 = helper(idx1 + 1, idx2)
        option2 = helper(idx1, idx2 + 1)
        
        return max(option1, option2, key=len)
    
    return helper()

seq1 = 'serendipitous'
seq2 = 'precipitation'
print(lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2)) # reipito
```

---

As a comparison, with `seq1 = 'serendipitous'` and `seq2 = 'precipitation'` `lcs_recursive_uncached(seq1, seq2)` makes 1119564 recursive calls, whereas `lcs_recursive_cached(seq1, seq2)` makes just 184 recursive calls!:

```
number_of_calls_uncached = 0
def lcs_recursive_uncached(seq1, seq2, idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0, lcs = ''):
    global number_of_calls_uncached
    number_of_calls_uncached += 1

    if idx1 == len(seq1) or idx2 == len(seq2):
        return lcs
        
    if seq1[idx1] == seq2[idx2]:
        return lcs_recursive_uncached(seq1, seq2, idx1 + 1, idx2 + 1, lcs + seq1[idx1])
    
    else:
        option1 = lcs_recursive_uncached(seq1, seq2, idx1 + 1, idx2, lcs)
        option2 = lcs_recursive_uncached(seq1, seq2, idx1, idx2 + 1, lcs)
        
        return max(option1, option2, key=len)

seq1 = 'serendipitous'
seq2 = 'precipitation'
print(number_of_calls_uncached) # 0
print(lcs_recursive_uncached(seq1, seq2)) # reipito
print(number_of_calls_uncached) # 1119564


from functools import lru_cache

number_of_calls_cached = 0
def lcs_recursive_cached(seq1, seq2):
    @lru_cache
    def helper(idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0):
        global number_of_calls_cached
        number_of_calls_cached += 1

        if idx1 == len(seq1) or idx2 == len(seq2):
            return ''
            
        if seq1[idx1] == seq2[idx2]:
            return  seq1[idx1] + helper(idx1 + 1, idx2 + 1)
        
        option1 = helper(idx1 + 1, idx2)
        option2 = helper(idx1, idx2 + 1)
        
        return max(option1, option2, key=len)
    
    return helper()

seq1 = 'serendipitous'
seq2 = 'precipitation'
print(number_of_calls_cached) # 0
print(lcs_recursive_cached(seq1, seq2)) # reipito
print(number_of_calls_cached) # 184
```

Comment: thanks sir for this detailed explanation :)    btw in  ```return max(option1, option2, key=len)``` the key= len means that max will return the option whichever has longest length right???

Comment: Yes, exactly. E.g. `print(max('Jack', 'Kilby', key=len))` prints `Kilby`, the longer string.

Answer (score 0):

To convert posted code to return the LCS rather than the length.

```
def lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0):
    
    if idx1 == len(seq1) or idx2 == len(seq2):
        return ""
        
    if seq1[idx1] == seq2[idx2]:
        return  seq1[idx1] + lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1 + 1, idx2 + 1)
    
    else:
        option1 = lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1 + 1, idx2)
        option2 = lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2, idx1, idx2 + 1)
        
        
        return max(option1, option2, key = len)
```

**Test**

```
seq1 = 'serendipitous' 
seq2 = 'precipitation'
                   
print(lcs_recursive(seq1, seq2))
# Output: 'reipito'
```

Comment: here in ``` return max(option1, option2, key = len) ```  the key = len means that max will return the max in terms of string length right?

Comment: @ShivaKharbanda -- it will return the longest length string.  For instance: `max('zz', 'aaa', key = len)` is 'aaa'.  But, `max('zz', 'aaa')` is 'zz'.